# Hooks from another package (useLocation...)

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, react-router-v4

I'm using a useLocation hook in my react project, and it works fine. When I create hook in react project it's works fine too.
BUT, when I create hook in other package, I've got error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'location' of undefined
```

And, if I move hook from package to react project, it will works.

P.S. From github [issue](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/7473)

Comment: ```useLocation``` is a valid hook only for the children of the wrapper from ```React Router```.

Comment: @CevaComic yeah, i know it. Please, read this sentence - `And, if I move hook from package to react project, it will works.`

Answer (score 0):

I decided this problem. It was in two packages of react-router-dom. In library I've used react and react-router-dom from lib/node_module, in app I've used react from lib/node_modules and react-router-dom from app/node_modules. I had had two different react-router-dom, when I link react-router-dom from App with react-router-dom in library, my code had started work fine.

This [comment](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/15706#issuecomment-503006137) had helped me. (but I linked react-router-dom instead react, 'cause react had been linked by create-react-library